# XPages: display DateTime value using browser's locale

Tags: datetime, xpages

I've some computed text on an XPage bound to a document data source, and trying display the date component of a Notes DateTime field using SSJS.

I've always used the doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray method, however it seems to be tied to the server's locale (if I change the browser's language from UK to US, the date format's still dd/mm/yyyy).

How do I output the date in a format that honours the browser's language setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a converter (that displays the data source value directly without using doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray):

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{document1.dateField}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime type="date"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getItemValueDateTimeArray()` method returns a list (`java.util.Vector` to be exact) of `NotesDateTime` values. The XPages runtime will only honour the browser's language setting if you pass it a `java.util.Date` object.

There are a couple of methods you can use.

Bind the computed field directly to the document's field (recommended approach):

```
<xp:text
   escape="true"
   id="computedField1"
   value="#{document1.$revisions}">
</xp:text>
```

Use the `toJavaDate()` method of the `NotesDateTime` class to return a `java.util.Date`:

```
<xp:text
   escape="true"
   id="computedField1"
   value="#{javascript:var doc = document1.getDocument();
     var dt:NotesDateTime = doc.getItemValueDateTimeArray('$revisions').get(0);
     return dt.toJavaDate();}">
</xp:text>
```

Once you have a `java.util.Date` object you can also add a converter to the field to format the date, but the samples above will already listen to the browser's locale.